# One button causing other button to disappear

Tags: css

So, I have two buttons: A and B

At beginning, only "A" is visible and "B" is hidden (such as opacity:0)

These two buttons are positioned at an identical position.

Is there a way in which when "A" is clicked, then "B" becomes visible and "A" is hidden?

For example

1. Before "A" is clicked: A=visible, B= not visible
2. After "A" is clicked: A= not visible B=visible.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I guess it cannot be achieved with CSS, better you can use jQuery to achieve this.

Comment: No need for jQuery, can be done with Vanilla javascript as well. But true, there's no way to achieve that with CSS, only.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the reply. I will do some research on it then. Thanks! (ps. this Vanilla js or jQuery, any suggestions to where I should start? thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use JQuery instead:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="a" name="a" value="A button" />
<input type="button" id="b" name="b" value="B button" />
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#a").on("click", function (eventObj) {
      $(this).hide();
      $("#b").show();
   });
});
```